# Content Security Policy, mod_pagespeeds и unsafe-inline

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, безопасность

Добрый день, сообщество! 
Пытаюсь внедрить CPS на сайте. На сервере установлен mod_pagespeeds, который, к моему удивлению, генерит кучу `eval` на странице. Вот кусок кода страницы:

```
<script>eval(mod_pagespeed_N_OeYaMDDO);</script>
<script>eval(mod_pagespeed_vvygFO_kog);</script>
```

Есть ли способ сказать mod_pagespeeds перестать генерить эвалы?

Comment: код лучше вставлять в виде текста (на stackoverflow предусмотрена подсветка кода, а для HTML/CSS/JS и выполнение при необходимости). А Ваши вопросы желательно сгруппировать и разделить для более качественных ответов

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском. Вы хорошие вопросы задаёте, но зачем-то поместили сразу три в один. Модель работы сайта предполагает, что вопросы «атомарны» — т.е. описывается одна проблема и можно написать компактный ответ, который эту проблему решит.  В том числе искать такие вопросы и ответы потом гораздо легче.

Comment: Поэтому, пожалуйста, выделите здесь какой-то один вопрос, а остальные опубликуйте самостоятельно. Пока что вопрос «закрыт» и на него отвечать нельзя — потому что неясно, на какой из трёх отвечать. Когда вы отредактируете вопрос, его переоткроют. Можете лично меня пингануть через `@Nick`, я открою. )

Comment: Если есть какие-то ещё вопросы по пользованию сайтом — обращайтесь, а также читайте справку ([help]) или Мету ([meta])

Comment: @NickVolynkin выделила главный вопрос, убрала лишние

Comment: @superpantera отлично, плюс вам )